# Java Selenium tests driver.close() and driver.quit() Firefox issue

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I am new in Selenium testing and I need to understand why my solution don't work with Firefox. 
I have a class Base which establishes the driver instance at @Before and close and quit driver on @After.
It looks like:

```
package tests;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import services.WebDriverService;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Base
{
    protected WebDriver driver;

    protected String baseUrl = "http://seleniumweb2";

    @Before
    public void before() throws IOException {
        this.driver = (new WebDriverService()).getDriver();
    }


    @After  // It can not be AfterClass because of closing browsers on remote server
    public void after()
    {
         driver.close();
         driver.quit();
    }    
}
```

As you can see after method calls close() and quit() methods. Chrome driver works without any problems but Firefox throws me an exception org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException As I remove close() it works. I found a few solutions from remove close() to catch Exception but I would like to know what is the best practice. I would catch the exception. Am I right? Like

```
@After  // It can not be AfterClass because of closing browsers on remote server
public void after()
{
    try {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();  // Is necessary to stop server node session!!!
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("driver.quit() throws exception while closing browser window.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using both `close()` and `quit()`? The documentation says `quit()` closes all windows anyway?

Comment: Do not use `driver.close();` use only `driver.quit();` for all drivers.

Comment: I am learning it. This solution comes from tutorial I am doing.

Comment: Yes I thing I understand the difference. Thnaks.